# How to get Rails to use an OAuth2 provider based on django-oauth-toolkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth, django-oauth

I'm trying to get a Rails app to use an external OAuth2 provider that I set up using django-oauth-toolkit. I'm using the omniauth-oauth2 strategy as a base and set up my own local URLs for the authentication and token URLs. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2

The redirect_uri that was sent during the authentication phase is slightly different than the one sent to get the token. It has extra parameters: state and code. django-oauth-toolkit is looking at this URL as being different than the original one because of the extra parameters. Wondering if this is a problem on the rails side, on the django side, or something to do with the way I have it set up.